# How is PHP fsockopen different from WebSockets in HTML5?

Tags: php, html, sockets

Is it only the server side vs. client side?

Can you have an instant message sent via PHP's fsockopen or am I limited due to polling with Javascript on the other side, the client?

Comment: websockets are a html5 facility. fsockopen is to open a regular tcp socket. you might have problems with fsockopen with firewalls and negotiation.

Comment: Can you tell me what "html5 facility" means?

Comment: maybe part of html5 spec is a better way to describe it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fsockopen creates the "normal" system sockets and thus can be used to connect to mail servers etc. WebSockets look similar at first but they are bidirectional data transfer encapsulated inside a HTTP(S) connection. This means, that you cannot use them to directly connect to mail servers etc. Instead you would need to have a WebSocket peer which forwards the data to plain sockets.